# Proof solution of $d_{x}\vec{g}(x)=H\vec{g}(x)$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have:

$d_{x}\vec{g}(x)=H\vec{g}(x)$

where $\vec{g}(x)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $H\in\mathbb{R}^{2*2}$

The solution is:

$\vec{g}(x)=c_{1}e^{\Lambda_{1}x}\vec{g_{1}}(x)+c_{2}e^{\Lambda_{2}x}\vec{g_{2}}(x)$

where $\vec{g_{1}}(x)$ and $\vec{g_{2}}(x)$ are the eigenvectors of $H$ and $\Lambda_{1}$, $\Lambda_{1}$ the eigenvalues.

I would like to **proof this.**

How you would do it, is to know that the solution can be written as:

1. $\vec{g}(x)=e^{Hx}\vec{g}(0)$
2. Diagonalize H, take the exponential of each diagonal component (eigenvalues), and project back to orignal space using the eigenvectors.

...but I somehow can not figure it out correctly.

EDIT:

- $H$ is diagonalizable.
- I would like to deduce the form of  $\vec{g}(x)$ from the ODE using
  the strategy that I scetched.

Comment: Do you know that $H$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes, $H$ is diagonalizable, thanks for the comment !

Comment: There are two ways to interpret "I would like to prove $g$ is the solution of $dg = Hg$": 1. You want to _verify_ that a particular $g$ satisfies the ODE; 2. You want to _deduce the form of $g$_ from the ODE. Your sketch of a strategy is only needed for 2. If instead you want to verify (which is suggested by the fact you know $g$), just calculate $dg$, using the fact that the $g_{i}$ are eigenvectors of $H$ with eigenvalue $\Lambda_{i}$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, I would like to deduce the form of 
g from the ODE using the strategy that I scetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IF* you knew that $H$ gave rise to an orthonormal basis $\{{\bf v}_1, {\bf v}_2\}$ of eigenvectors for $\mathbb{R}^2$ (such as if $H$ were symmetric), then define $g_1(x) = ({\bf g}(x) \cdot {\bf v}_1)$ and $g_2(x) = ({\bf g}(x) \cdot {\bf v}_2)$. Now, by orthogonality, ${\bf g}(x) = g_1(x) {\bf v}_1 + g_2(x) {\bf v}_2$ and you will find that 
$$
e^{Hx} {\bf g}(0) = g_1(0) e^{Hx}{\bf v}_1 + g_2(0) e^{H x} {\bf v}_2 = g_1(0) e^{\lambda_1 x}{\bf v}_1 + g_2(0) e^{\lambda_2 x} {\bf v}_2
$$
which, since ${\bf v}_1$ and ${\bf v}_2$ are eigenvectors of $H$, is in the general form you suggest. However, this argument only applies when the eigenvectors are orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont't see how you go from  $g_1(0) e^{Hx}{\bf v}_1 + g_2(0) e^{H x} {\bf v}_2 = g_1(0) e^{\lambda_1 x}{\bf v}_1 + g_2(0) e^{\lambda_2 x} {\bf v}_2$

Comment: If ${\bf A}$ is a square matrix and ${\bf v}$ is an eigenvector of ${\bf A}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then ${\bf v}$ is also an eigenvector of $e^{\bf A}$ with eigenvalue $e^{\lambda}$. To prove this, $$e^{\bf A}{\bf v} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} {\bf A}^k {\bf v} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \lambda^k {\bf v} = e^{\lambda} {\bf v}$$

Comment: you are using the series expansion of the exponential, but to me this equality only holds if A is álready diagonalized. I don't see why in the geraeral case this should be true ?

Comment: The series expansion is the general definition of the exponentiated matrix, whether or not ${\bf A}$ is diagonalizable (as long as it is square so it makes sense to take powers).

Comment: Yes, - I am sorry if I am bothering you-, but I don't see why you can say that the second equality holds (between the two sums) ?

Comment: Since ${\bf A} {\bf v} = \lambda {\bf v}$ then ${\bf A}^2 {\bf v} = {\bf A}({\bf A} {\bf v}) = {\bf A}(\lambda{\bf v}) = \lambda {\bf A}{\bf v} = \lambda^2 {\bf v}$...  Also, to avoid confusion, note that ${\bf A}^0$ is defined as the identity matrix ${\bf I}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now.